# Why does $\text{Span}\{[3, 2]\}$ correspond to $2x−3y=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

A question from the **Coding The Matrix** book, example 3.3.9

The line can be represented as $\text{Span}\{[3, 2]\}$ but it can also be represented as $\{[x,y]\in\mathbb{R}^2 : 2x−3y=0\}$.

That is, the line is the solution set of a homogeneous linear equation.

Could you please explain me the rationale and theory behind this statement? Why does not $\text{Span}\{[2,3]\}$ then?

[image]

The author's link to the book: Philip N. Klein, *[Linear Algebra through Computer Science Applications](https://github.com/akinguyen/Coding_the_matrix/blob/892166ca41f49a46e52e4957c8f1b88f14d79093/Philip%20N.%20Klein-Coding%20the%20Matrix_%20Linear%20Algebra%20through%20Computer%20Science%20Applications-Newtonian%20Press%20(2013).pdf)*, Newtonian Press, 2013.

Comment: Hint: $2x-3y=0$ (the line through zero) is a one-dimensional vector space and the vector $(x,y)=(3,2)$ is a non zero vector in it. Hence?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Why Span is not {2,3} then?

Comment: @Pasha The span of the vector is all multiples of the vector. Since $0(2.3)=(0,0)$ and $1(2,3)=(2,3)$, the span of $(2,3)$ would be the line through those two points. What is the slope of that line? Your line has a slope of $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you. How can I derive the span for 3-vector? What’s the translation?

Comment: The span of $a\hat i+b\hat j+c\hat k$ is the line that goes through the origin and $(a,b,c)$. Therefore, we get $(x,y,z)=(ta,tb,tc)$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$. Recall from your multivariable calculus course how to translate that into two equations involving $x,y,z,a,b,c$.

Answer (score 2):

The equation \(2x - 3y = 0\) represents a line in the \(xy\)-plane. This equation is a homogeneous linear equation, meaning it has no constant term and includes the origin.

The span of the vector \([3, 2]\) also represents the same line. The span of a vector includes all its scalar multiples, essentially covering all possible combinations of that vector.

In essence, both the equation and the vector's span describe the same line in two-dimensional space. The equation characterizes the line as a solution set of a homogeneous linear equation, while the vector's span encompasses all possible linear combinations of that vector, which align with the equation's representation of the line.

Comment: Why Span is not {2,3} then?

Comment: The equation 2x - 3y = 0 defines a line in the xy-plane. It's a homogeneous linear equation without a constant term.

The span of the vector [3, 2] represents the same line. It includes all possible combinations of the vector [3, 2] scaled by different values.

The span isn't {2, 3} because it's about combinations of the vector [3, 2], not just its components. The span encompasses all potential linear combinations of the vector [3, 2] in forming the line.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind writing a translation formula from span to the vector and from the vector to the span?

Comment: Pasha: for any a,b: span {[a,b]} = line bx-ay=0. And conversely for any c,d line cx+dy=0 is span {[d,-c]}.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the line $2x-3y=0$ corresponds to the set of points $$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|2x-3y=0\}.$$ Now, solving $2x-3y=0$ for $y$, we have $y=\frac{2}{3}x$. Therefore, $$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|2x-3y=0\}=\{x(1,\frac{2}{3})|x\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
Let us change the variable $x$ to $x^\prime$ as follows $x=3x^\prime$. Therefore, $$\{x(1,\frac{2}{3})|x\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{x^\prime(3,2)|x^\prime\in\mathbb{R}\}=\text{Span}\{(3,2)\}.$$Therefore, $$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|2x-3y=0\}=\text{Span}\{(3,2)\}.$$ **"Why does not $\text{Span}\{(2,3)\}$ then?"**

Since $2\cdot 2-3\cdot 3\neq0$, it follows that $(2,3)\notin\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|2x-3y=0\}$. Therefore, $\text{Span}\{(2,3)\}$ does not span $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|2x-3y=0\}$.

Comment: It is the same as retracing the steps you have already written, but it might be helpful to point out that along with your implication, $a\in \text{Span}\{(2,3)\}\implies a$ lies on the line, so that it is clear to OP that the two statements mean precisely the same thing.